# Modifying back button with react-navigation on specific screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Here I'm using `react-navigation` as my navigation library.

How can I change the `back` button (that is added automatically by `react-navigation`) functionality for a specific screen?

I mean instead of going one step in the stack of screens I want it to go 2 steps back in stack or do it manually by giving the screen name (again only on one component).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom back navigation for reactnavigation back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074451/custom-back-navigation-for-reactnavigation-back-button)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can override back button for a specific screen with `navigationOptions` of that screen. You can read more info about overriding back button in [`react-navigation` docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons.html#overriding-the-back-button)

*Example from docs*

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: <LogoTitle />,
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
        title="Info"
        color="#fff"
      />
    ),
  };
}
```

> **Overriding the back button**
>
> The back button will be rendered automatically in a `StackNavigator`
>   whenever it is possible for the user to go back from their current
>   screen — in other words, the back button will be rendered whenever
>   there is more than one screen in the stack.
>
> Generally, this is what you want. But it's possible that in some
>   circumstances that you want to customize the back button more than you
>   can through the options mentioned above, in which case you can specify
>   a `headerLeft`, just as we did with `headerRight`, and completely
>   override the back button.

Comment: is there a way to change only the `onPress()` function ?
I want to keep the initial back image

Comment: @greW not directly I believe. But you can check the source code for navigation bar for react-native and see if you can import the same button they use for back and then override onPress prop. But I think using a custom button would be simpler.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll mark it as the answer as you helped me to achieve it.

for whoever that needs that arrow you can simple Import that component and just override the the `onPress` prop.
`import { HeaderBackButton } from 'react-navigation'`

Comment: @greW you can edit my answer with the small example of how you used `HeaderBackButton` that would be perfect.

Comment: @greW is it possible to show alert box to get user conformation on HeaderBackButton before navigating to other screen

Comment: What if I don't want to override the back button text for a specific screen, rather I just want to override the default 'Back' text?

Answer (score 43):

Consider, that you have 3 screens A, B, C respectively.
So, the default functionality of the back button in StackNavigator is:-
If you press the Back Button on screen C, it will take you to the previous screen i.e, screen B.
To override that you could do something like this on screen C:-

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from 'react-navigation';
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return{
    headerLeft:(<HeaderBackButton onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('A')}}/>)
 }
}
```

Comment: Use `labelVisible={false}` and `tintColor={'#FFF'}` for more customization, 
All props in [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/stack/blob/64c14bb20a8cf1b0c060f3ee338528346bb59625/src/types.tsx#L161)

Comment: I cant use static in my code saying = Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)

Comment: With the latest version, it now needs to be imported from `@react-navigation/elements`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#headerbackbutton

Answer (score 11):

If you are on version 5, and are dealing with a functional component, you can use a layout effect hook to accomplish this ([example from the docs reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#setoptions)):

```
function ProfileScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState(route.params.title);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: value === '' ? 'No title' : value,
    });
  }, [navigation, value]);
```

Note that if you are changing `headerLeft`, you may need to pass a function to it ([GH issue reference](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7773#issuecomment-598776460)).

Answer (score 10):

By default, HeaderBackButton component is used. You can implement it and use it to override the back button styles, press props, for example:
link to [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headerleft)

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  custom: {
  // Custom styles here
  }
});

<Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{
    headerLeft: (props) => (
      <HeaderBackButton
        {...props}
        style={styles.custom}
        onPress={() => {
        // Do something
        }}
      />
    ),
  }}
/>;
```

If you want full control, you can use your custom back button component, example:

```
import { CustomBackButton } from 'path/to/custom/component';

<Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{
    headerLeft: (props) => (
      <CustomBackButton {...props} />
    ),
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: This was helpful but I was getting "error check header render method" since I'm using version 6 I needed to also import react-navigation/elements per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70109447/16743381)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this while creating the stack navigator as well. Updated as of react-navigation v4.

```
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderBackButton } from "react-navigation-stack";

const yourStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SomeRoute: SomeScreen,
  SpecificRoute: {
    screen: SpecificScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: (<HeaderBackButton onPress={_ => navigation.navigate("Somewhere")}/>)
    })
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

## Efficient Navigation

Imagine you have three screens in your app: A, B, and C.

You start on screen A, and after interacting with a component, you navigate to screen B.

Once you're on screen B, you can manage navigation with the following code:

```js
// This code snippet handles the event after the back button is pressed
navigation.pop();  // This removes screen B from the navigation stack
navigation.navigate("C");  // This navigates to screen C
```

With this approach, you are now on screen C. If you press the `back` button, the navigation will take you back to screen A since screen B has been popped off the stack.

An alternative method is to use `replace`:

```js
// This code snippet handles the event after the back button is pressed
navigation.replace("C");  // This replaces screen B with screen C in the navigation stack
```

Using `replace` will switch out screen B for screen C. If the `back` button is used now, it will not go to screen B, because screen B has been replaced, and you will go back to the preceding screen in the stack, which might be A depending on your navigation stack's history.