# Custom back navigation for reactnavigation back button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How can I give a custom navigation to the header back arrow in ReactNavigation? I want the back arrow in the header to navigate to the screen I define and not to the previous screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Just pass in your own component, which when clicked pushes whatever page you want onto the StackNavigator.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try 2 things:

a) use `headerMode: 'none'` in your `sub-StackRouters` instead of your root router (named RouterComponent). Ideally you shouldn't have to do anything more then and the headers of the `sub-StackRouters` would be displayed in your root router's header. I think I remember something similarly worked a while back for me, but I haven't tested it in a while now and I think it's unlikely that it will still work like this but you can test nevertheless.

b) and this is what I'm currently using in a different situation. To manually include the back button:

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />,
})

const RouterComponent = StackNavigator({
    Tabs: {
        screen: Tabs
    },
    Profile: {
        screen: ProfileStack,
        navigationOptions
    }
},{
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

If above solution doesn't work,

Try to add navigationOptions directly to the ProfileStack definition.

```
const ProfileStack = StackNavigator({
    ProfileHome: { 
      screen: ProfileHome, 
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({ //don't forget parentheses around the object notation
        title: 'Profile',
        headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)} />
      })
    },
    ProfileEdit: { screen: ProfileEdit }
  }
```

Comment: HeaderBackButton is not part of `react-navigation` now... Where I can get it?

Comment: @Baterka `HeaderBackButton` has been moved to `react-navigation-stack`

Comment: `HeaderBackButton` [has been moved](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/commit/55e6f3dd3301231ea4646d0c3f9a1f9449657703#diff-7ba17716fa24e2bdc6448b98b3e7b66069ae153921aba22718ea2d9078aecd66) to `@react-navigation/elements`.

Comment: what if i want to save the data before going back? where should i put the save or validating logic?

Answer (score 12):

Hi who ever is using react-navigation 5.x you might not be able to make navigation using `navigationOptions`. The option is been replaced with `options`.

Say your in screen -1 and navigated to screen-2 and then to screen-3. By default using react-navigation you can navigate from screen-3 to screen-2. But if you want customised navigation i.e., Say from above example if you want to navigate from screen-3 to screen-1.

If you would like to retain the view of back button and only override the onPress method, you can `import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/stack'` and assign that component to the `headerLeft` option.

Example:

```
<RootStack.Screen
    name="dashboard"
    component={Dashboard}
    options={({navigation, route}) => ({
          headerLeft: (props) => (
            <HeaderBackButton
              {...props}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
            />
          ),
     })}
  />
```

In above example on click of back button in Dashboard screen takes you to Home screen.

Enjoy & Thanks
-Sukshith

Comment: `HeaderBackButton` [has been moved](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/commit/55e6f3dd3301231ea4646d0c3f9a1f9449657703#diff-7ba17716fa24e2bdc6448b98b3e7b66069ae153921aba22718ea2d9078aecd66) to `@react-navigation/elements`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for React Navigation 6.x is as follows:

Use the HeaderBackButton from the `@react-navigation/elements` package.

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/elements';

const Main = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // handle header left button press and navigate to desired screen
  const handlePress = useCallback(
    () => navigation.navigate('to the screen you desire'),
    []
  );

  // create header left button
  const headerLeft = useCallback(
    () => <HeaderBackButton onPress={handlePress} />,
    [handlePress],
  );

  // add header left button to the header
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft,
    });
  }, [navigation, headerLeft]);

  // return what you want to show
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a `beforeRemove` listener for when the current screen is about to be removed

```
navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
  if (everyThingIsGoodAlready) {
    // If we don't need to do anything, then just go back as usual
    return;
  }

  // Prevent default behavior of leaving the screen
  e.preventDefault();

  // Add any custom actions we need to take. E.g:
  // const customAction = () => {...}
  // customAction();


  /* 
    If you are all good and you want to continue with closing, 
    then you can dispatch the action you blocked earlier with e.preventDefault() 

    This will continue the action that had triggered the removal of the screen
  */
  navigation.dispatch(e.data.action);

})
```

Reference the [official docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/) for more information and limitations to this method: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/