# How to skip back/modify navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have a stackNavigation which works great. 3 screens : DeviceList / DeviceDetail / DevideAdd. The normal paths is (1) DeviceList > DeviceDetail or (2) DeviceList > DeviceAdd > DeviceDetail.

But when user use the path (2), I want that the back button of the DeviceDetail screen go to DeviceList. Or for the moment, it's going to DevideAdd.

Here is my navigation:

```
const DeviceStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    DeviceList: {
        screen: DeviceList,
    },
    DeviceDetail: {
        screen: DeviceDetail,
    },
    DeviceAdd: {
        screen: DeviceAdd,
    },
});
```

How to achieve it ?

Comment: Ok, did you already try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49477330/modifying-back-button-with-react-navigation-on-specific-screen

Comment: OK it works with custom navigation options in DeviceDetail. I got the left arrow which is going to DeviceList but I don't achieve to custom left arrow title. It is blank. Any idea ? I already try "headerBackTitle"...

Comment: Ok I found it: I had to add "title={'custom title'} backTitleVisible={true}" in the headerLeft > HeaderBackButton params. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The key attribute '`goBack()`' is a dynamically generated string that is created each time you navigate to a new '`react-navigation`' path.

So if you want to go from `DeviceDetail` to `DeviceList`, what you have to do is to pass the key of `DeviceAdd` down to `DeviceDetail`, and then call `goBack()` with the key.

**DeviceAdd.js**

```js
render() {
    const { state, navigate } = this.props.navigation;    

    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Go to DeviceDetail" onPress={ () => {
                navigate('DeviceDetail', { go_back_key: state.key });
            }} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

**DeviceDetail.js**

```js
render() {
    const { state, goBack } = this.props.navigation;    
    const params = state.params || {};

    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Back to DeviceList" onPress={ () => {
                goBack(params.go_back_key);
            }} />
        </View>
    );
}
```